# Mirror Matter Hypothesis?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model

What is the current state of the hypothesis of [mirror matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_matter) today?
Are there any experimental data or theoretical arguments that exclude it by now, or is it still considered viable among physicists?

The relationship between mirror matter and ordinary matter is different from matter-antimatter which are related by space-time reflection.

As far as I can make out Matter-Mirror matter is hypothesised to be related by space reflection alone.

Mirror matter theorists like Dr.Robert Foot [believe that dark matter might be made up of mirror hydrogen and mirror helium.](http://uk.arxiv.org/find/astro-ph/1/au%3a+Foot_R/0/1/0/all/0/1)

Comment: Can't say anything about the theory, but *"matter-antimatter [...] are related by space-time reflection."* is simply not correct. However, I would guess without detailed knowledge that mirror matter will have a hard time explaining (1) why there is so much more dark matter (2) the distribution of the dark matter galactic halos and (3) the bullet cluster microlensing results all at the same time.

Comment: Hi John - it sounds like you're just asking for general opinions here, which isn't appropriate for this site. A question that simply asks "What do people think of..." is usually going to be too vague and inviting of discussion, as described in our [FAQ#dontask]. If you edit the question to be more specific about what you would like to know about this theory, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: I've voted to re-open on the basis of @Dilaton's edit, which I think makes it specific enough to belong on the site.

Comment: Thanks, @Nathaniel. I have set a flag too asking if it could be reopend now.